# Android: How to handle context menu click from within custom view

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am trying to create a self contained custom `ListView` and want to handle all the events on that ListView from within the custom view class itself. This custom view would go into a library and may be used from within different activities and fragments.

The only problem I seem to be facing is to handle context menu clicks from within my ListView.

I register for context menu handling using `Activity.registerForContextMenu(View)` during `onAttachedToWindow()` handler and unregister it during `onDetachedFromWindow()`, so that I do not have to register from within the activity. However, I still can't find a way to get a callback to something like `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem)` within my custom view.

Is there a way for my custom view to handle the clicks on context MenuItems provided by it without putting code in each activity they are part of?

Also, Kindly give a reason if you downvote or you think its an idiotic thing to segregate event handling into a custom view.

Comment: It's actually a fair question... there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is by implementing your context menu for your list view instead of mixing it together with the actions that belong to the activity.

All you'd have to do is register a `OnItemLongClickListener`:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

and implement the `onItemLongClick` method. For example:

```
private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   if (mAlertDialog != null) {
      mAlertDialog.dismiss();
   } 
   mAlertDialog = new ActionsForTheItemInTheListViewDialog(view, position);
   mAlertDialog.show();
}
```

where `ActionsForTheItemInTheListViewDialog` would be some class that extends `AlertDialog` and would show different options for that item. That way the logic for custom component would be completely encapsulated within your library.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This looks good. However, will it not make any context menu items added in the parent views inaccessible. For example, it may be possible that the parent fragment or the activity may want to add some context menu items themselves, say for example to refresh the entire activity. I think there must be a way for making the menuitem clicks bubble down to components. Otherwise, how would the builtin components handle context menu? We never add any code in the activities for their handling.